# How to connect to a mongoDb replica created with Docker compose from mongo express and mongo-Compass

Tags: mongodb, docker

**Problem:**

I have created a mongo Db replica set like this using docker-compose.

```
questionsdb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: questionsdb
    hostname: questionsdb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mi1234
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/dbadmin
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
      - 9229:9229
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rsmongo", "--bind_ip_all"]
    #networks: 
    #  - custom-

  questionsdb1:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: questionsdb1
    hostname: questionsdb1
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mi1234
    volumes:
      - mongo_data1:/data/dbadmin
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
      - 9230:9229
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rsmongo", "--bind_ip_all"]
    #networks: 
    #  - custom-network

  questionsdb2:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: questionsdb2
    hostname: questionsdb2
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mi1234
    volumes:
      - mongo_data2:/data/dbadmin
    expose:
        - "27017"
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
      - 9231:9229
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rsmongo", "--bind_ip_all"]
    #networks: 
    #  - custom-network
```

And my mongo-express container configuration is like this.

```
mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8111:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=questionsdb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=mi1234
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin@mi.com
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=mi@1234
    #networks: 
    #  - custom-network
```

And I try to connect to it through mongo Compass like this.

```
mongodb://admin:mi1234@localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/admin?replicaSet=rsmongo
```

But both mongo-express and mongo compass was failed with giving me authentication failed.

This is the error I can see in the docker container.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-16T01:57:15.391+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn219","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","speculative":false,"principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"172.18.0.15:59638","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"admin\" for db \"admin\""}}
```

Can someone help me to solve this. I tried a lot to find out a solution to this but I was unable to do so. Thank you

Comment: Does the connection work outside of the replicaset? I mean if you connect to a single instance like so `mongodb://admin:mi1234@localhost:27017/admin`. Then, could you post the authentication failing message?

Comment: @MartinTovmassian Yes, it is failing for that one too. I have edited the question with the error

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message no admin user has been created in your DB during the container startup.

This could be explained by your custom entrypoint `[ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rsmongo", "--bind_ip_all"]` that overrides the official one. Whereas the root user creation work seems to be achieved by this [script](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh).

Try to execute your docker-compose stack with only one mongo instance and without the entrypoint statement.